# Finding an injective envelope containing another injective envelope

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, injective-modules

Let $R$ be a local principal ideal domain (PID) with only two prime ideals $0$ and $P$, and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Let for $r\in R$ and $m\in M$, $rm\not=0$. Now if $E(rm)$ is a fixed injective envelope for $rm$, then can we find an injective envelope for $m$ containing $E(rm)$?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for an "invective envelop" ? Maybe, it is also worth saying what is an injective envelop for an element of a module.

Comment: I am looking for an injective envelope $A$ for $m$ such that $E(rm)\subseteq A$.

Comment: What is “an injective envelope for an element”? The standard definition is for an injective envelope of a module.